# Android How to be Notified at a Specific Time

Tags: java, android

When my Android app reaches a specific time (say, 1400 hours) the app should do a specific thing, such as enter a Night Mode. At no other time would the app want to do this, and it seems like a waste to poll for this time. Is there a way to have Android notify my app when this time is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an alarm with [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Answer (score 1):

Create a alaram manager and give it a pending intent, this intent will have the code which you want execute at that moment